# XSL-FO: displaying Arabic characters

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Please, I have a problem displaying the Arabic language in my reports generated in PDF format using the api fop 1.0 (XSL-FO).
I configured a userConfig.xml for using Arial.ttf font. everything works fine except that characters are displayed separately. 
example: ت ق و ل instead of تقول 
I put spaces only to explain to you.

```
<fo:block-container font-size="12pt" writing-mode="rl-tb"  xml:lang="ar" font-family="Arial" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
<fo:block>
تقول
</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

I tried to use the tag  but its contents do not appear in the generated doc.

```
<fo:block text-align="center"> 
<fo:inline direction="rtl" language="ar" unicode-bidi="embed">
تقول
</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

userConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Arial Unicode only -->
<fop version="1.0">
  <renderers>
   <renderer mime="application/pdf">
       <fonts>
           <!-- register a particular font -->
           <font kerning="yes"
                 embed-url="file:///C:\windows\arial.ttf"
                 encoding-mode="single-byte">
               <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
           </font>
       </fonts>
   </renderer>
</renderers>
</fop>
```

- head of my xsl

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Support for Arabic and other complex scripts may be disabled in FOP, see [FOP complex scripts](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.0/complexscripts.html).

If they are enabled, setting lang="ar" should be enough.

complex-scripts-disabled should be 'false'

Comment: I added the following line in my config file, but the problem persists. <complex-scripts disabled="true"/>

Comment: if you disable complex scripts, FOP won't support Arabic. So that setting should be 'false'.

Comment: even in false the result does not change

Comment: I believe Complex scripts is FOP 2.0 feature

Comment: Arabic was added in 2011, it seems: https://people.apache.org/~spepping/

Comment: is fop 2.0 compatible with jdk 1.4?

Comment: I checked fop2.0 and fop1.1 are not compatible with jdk 1.4