# FOP Arabic letter spacing

Tags: fonts, arabic, xsl-fo, apache-fop, letter-spacing

I am generating multi-lingual PDF using Apache FOP 2.5, including Latin, Cyrillic and Arabic characters.
I managed to include the proper fonts, and I was able to deal with the right-to-left display for Arabic, when needed.

However I am facing an issue with letter-spacing in Arabic characters : the characters are spaced out from each other. This is what I see in the generated PDF

[image]

But this is what I have in the original XML (please note how the Arabic characters are close to each other) :

[image]

I am using the Deja Vu font and I have computed the metrics of the font using what is described [here](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/fonts.html).

How can I solve this ?

I have read [this article](https://coderanch.com/t/127015/languages/Journal-Article-Creating-Multiple-Language) which basically inserts `letter-spacing="-2pt"` everytime the string to be displayed is in Arabic. But I don't want to hardcode tests on the language in the stylesheet.

Any help appreciated !

**EDIT** :

- Using FOP 2.5
- I confirm that `complex-script` is enabled (added a debug message to be sure)
- I had set `kerning="yes"` set in the config file

Comment: Found similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532386/xsl-fo-displaying-arabic-characters

Comment: Are you stuck on FOP 1.1?  The current version is FOP 2.5 (though I have no idea if it actually does Arabic any better). AFAICT, FOP 1.1 dates from 2012.

Comment: Adding `letter-spacing` isn't going to fix this anyway. You can't just smash together Arabic letters; they change shape depending on where they are in the word. "مُتغلى" doesn't look anything like "مُ ت غ ل ى". I suspect you've turned off "complex-scripts" somewhere (as mentioned in your linked answer). I'd also try removing all styling (specifically italic, which may not work correctly with Arabic. The concept of "italic" doesn't precisely translate into Arabic script, and support for it is spotty.) I'd also try being explicit with `language="ar"`.

Comment: I just updated to FOP 2.5 and have the same behavior

Comment: I haven't touched anaything related to complex scripts, which I read is enabled by default. If that matters, FOP is initialized from a config file read from a Java application where it is embedded. I will try enabling complex sciprts explicitely.

Comment: Consider that the font metrics for that font are just wrong. Test it by switching the font to Arial and see if it is not better, then it is likely the font.

Comment: Consider replacing the _image_ of the source FO elements with the actual _XML code_, so as to provide an example people can use to quickly replicate your problem and check what goes wrong.

Comment: Note that font metrics are needed no more in recent versions of FOP; removing them from the font configuration would allow you to check whether they are the source of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the very valuable comments received, I was able to solve the problem by :

1. Upgrading to FOP 2.5
2. Switching to another Font (Traditional Arabic instead of Deja Vu)
3. And, as FOP 2.5 does not require a font metrics file, removing the font metrics.

In the meanwhile I saw that embedding the fonts in my application was more difficult in FOP 2.5 than in FOP 1.1 because it is harder to set relative URLs in FOP font configuration. I was able to solve this with [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40509128/189723).