# apache Fop separated arabic charcters

Tags: java, xslt, apache-fop

I am trying to generate PDF from xml using apache Fop,
It works fine with english but while i try to disply arabic text the characters are separated as shown in the Image

[image]

1- I tried with 2.1, 2.5 and latest stable apache Fop version  2.6

2- I embded the font in Fop config file

3- I enabled complex-scripts

4- I tried with different fonts

but it didn't solve the issue
I attached Apache Fop configuration file below

```
<fop version="1.0">
    <complex-scripts disabled="false" />
    <renderers lang="ar">
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <fonts>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="src/main/resources/fonts/trado.ttf" embedding-mode="auto" encoding="UTF-8">
                    <font-triplet name="trado-ar-font" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                </font>
            </fonts>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>
</fop>
```

I also checked:
[XSL-FO: displaying Arabic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532386/xsl-fo-displaying-arabic-characters) and
[FOP Arabic letter spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65309548/fop-arabic-letter-spacing)

but there is nothing worked with me
appriciate any support please

Comment: Can you add the FO markup corresponding to your sample image? For those of us that don't read Arabic, can you also fake an image of what it should look like?

Comment: I think the `lang="ar"` attribute must be in the FO file, not in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

refrence to https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.0/complexscripts.html
It was solved by adding script="arab" to the root tag like:

```html
 <fo:root script="arab">
```